# Print at smaller scale

Tags: macos, printing

I recently received a PDF document consisting of 2 landscape A4 documents, which I would like to print as 1 portrait A4 (or 2 A5). I'm missing the control panel to print at 50% with matching layout. How can I do this on OS X?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce size and fit to patch size with Preview (which is the default application for PDFs). In the print dialog, select paper size and adjustments as required:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank for all your suggestions! With them, I found the following solution. A little disclaimer first: I don't have my Mac that long, and printing on a Mac was entirely new to me until last week. It can all be done without additional software on OS X 10.8.4, maybe on older version too (i don't know).

First, open the the 'Show Details' pane (i totally missed that). 
[image]

Then, open the layout sub pane (1) and change 'Pages per Sheet' (2). The printer driver automatically scaled down the pages to fit. As you can see, this is a Brother MFC-J4410DW,  so maybe your mileage differs with another printer driver.

[image]